# Realm Cocoa: skipped item when iterating through RLMArray

Tags: cocoa, swift, realm

I have a very strange issue when iterating through RLMArray. I do something like this:

```
let tickets = Ticket.objectsWhere("pendingSync = true")

for ticket in tickets {
    print("1. " + ticket.id + ",")
}

realm.beginWriteTransaction()
for ticket in tickets {
    let ticket = ticket as Ticket        
    ticket.pendingSync = false

    print("2. " + ticket.id + ",")
}
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

Strangely enough, the output is

`1. 125, 1. 127, 1. 123, 
2. 125, 2. 123`

and NOT

`1. 125, 1. 127, 1. 123, 
2. 125, 2. 127, 2. 123`

Shortly, the second iteration skips one item. How is this possible? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are some of the items being deleted or marked 'false' in another thread? Note that when you beginTransaction() all objects are refreshed with any other changes done in other threads. If you don't want that behaviour, you can beginTransaction() before the initial tickets assignment (query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutating items during enumeration is not currently supported in Realm, but will be supported in the upcoming 0.95 release.